# Issue with time cell - adding 24 minutes

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xls

I use apache poi 3.7 and java 7.

I have problem with time cell output in excel in .xls format. Hours and minutes are stored as one value in database in double. 
If I pass value 1.0 in generated xls file will be display as 1h 24 min. Unfortunately this problem not occur locally. I dont have access to data and I cannot repeat this problem on my local environment.

Below is code where i initialize workbook and format of problematic cell:

```
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(template);
DateFormat df = workbook.createDataFormat();
CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
style.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("h:mm"));
```

Below is used function to create cell. Function get argument value from database:

```
private void createTimeCell(Row r, int pos, double value) {
    int hours = (int) value;
    int minutes = (int) Math.round((value - hours) * 60);
    Date date = new Date(0, 0, 1);
    date.setHours(hours);
    date.setMinutes(minutes);
    Cell c = r.createCell(pos);     
    c.setCellValue(date);
    c.setCellStyle(style);
}
```

Comment: Looks OK to me. Are you sure `value` contains `1.0` ?

Comment: To avoid some of the conversions going on between java.util.Date and Excel, you could use `c.setCellFormula("TIME("+hours+","+minutes+",00)");` instead of `c.setCellValue(...)` and see if that is any better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dates and times in Excel are stored as floating point numbers, the integer part being the days since 1900 / 1904, and the remainder as the time as a fraction of a day.

As such, you can probably make your code much simpler by just doing it as:

```
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(template);
DateFormat df = workbook.createDataFormat();
CellStyle timeStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
timeStyle.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("h:mm"));

private void createTimeCell(Row r, int pos, double hoursAndMinutes) {
    Cell c = r.getCell(pos, Row.CREATE_NUL_AS_BLANK);
    c.setCellValue(hoursAndMinutes / 24);
    c.setCellStyle(timeStyle);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I will check on production server.